# MongoDB Docker container refuses connection when auth enabled

Tags: mongodb, docker

If I set up my container without auth eg)

`docker run --name some-mongo -d -p 27017:27017 mongo`

I can connect to my mongoDB from a remote machine eg)

`mongo [serverIP]`

However, my issue is when using the `--auth` flag

Following the documentation:

`docker run --name some-mongo -d -p 27017:27017 mongo --auth`

```
> db.createUser({ user: 'foo', pwd: 'bar', roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] })
```

results in connections being refused:

```
$ mongo -u foo -p bar [serverIP]             
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: [serverIP]
2017-12-09T14:01:41.114-0600 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to [serverIP]:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-12-09T14:01:41.115-0600 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server [serverIP]:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I double-checked and the port looks to be open on the server:

```
$ netstat -tuplen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
...
tcp6       0      0 :::27017                :::*                    LISTEN      0          53238875   -                   
...
```

(Docker is running on a debian Digital Ocean droplet)

Comment: What does `docker logs` or running without `-d` show when using `--auth`?

Comment: Start with a named volume and without auth enabled, connect, create the [required users](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#user-administrator) and your database users, stop and remove container. Create a new container reusing the named volume and auth enabled. Alternative: start container as you did, `docker exec -it some-mongo mongo` and create the according users. However, you should use a named volume for your databases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `--authenticationDatabase` flag

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

see the [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/enable-authentication/)